# How could I use my racing wheel pedals in other games?

Tags: controllers

I dunno if someone has ever thought of this before, but Googling about it has turned up absolutely nothing. I'd like to be able to use my Logitech Momo Racing wheel pedals as extra buttons in some games. Namely, bind some panic abilities to them in a MMO game, and in general, just have something accessible just by the thump of my foot.

Another use would be to bind it as a push to talk key for ventrilo\mumble\etc. Any help appreciated!

Comment: I would investigate some form of macro for the 'button' so pressing it initiated a macro of sorts. Pressing keys for you.

Comment: Times like this make me miss the ability to reference the "How to PVP with a steering wheel" WoW thread...

Comment: @grace Very very strongly considered posting it as an answer...

Comment: @LessPop You *actually saved it*? You rock! Now, they exist in some form of posterity! Hidden (as you deleted it), but AWESOME.

Comment: @grace I can undelete if you want... I was somewhat uncertain about whether I should post it as the very first answer here...

Comment: @Less I'm actually uncertain about whether it should be undeleted - mostly because I'm hesitant of this classifying under the 3rd and 4th bullet points under [what not to ask in our FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq). All I know is that I can look at it whenever I want, now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be able to do it:  http://glovepie.org/glovepie_download.php

I used it to link a nintendo wii controller to a pc a while back.  Its basically a bridge between any sort of input device and a pc.  You tell it how to interpret different commands it receives from the device.  Exceptionally versatile.  Will take a little time to figure out though.

Don't let the enviro/political ramble on the site throw you off.  It really is a pretty good product and its free.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on OSX, you can try [Joystick Mapper](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/joystick-mapper/id528183797?mt=12). I've successfully mapped input from a Logitech Driving Force wheel to keyboard output.

Answer (score -1):

What about GIMX - Game Input Multiplexer (http://blog.gimx.fr/). I used it to connect my old Microsoft Sidewinder Wheel to a PS4. You can map any function to any button or axis.

From their website:

> The purpose of this free software is to control a video game console with a computer (e.g. a PC or a Raspberry Pi). It works with the PS3, the Xbox 360, the PS4 and the Xbox One... The application gets data from the peripherals (mice, keyboards and joysticks) and sends controls to the game console over bluetooth or usb. Other controls such as gesture or voice are possible through the use of external software that emulate peripherals.

Comment: Is there a reason for the -1? Would like to know it so that I could edit my answer appropriately.